# Two Dell representatives told me that Windows 7 Ultimate allows multiple simultaneous remote desktop connections

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Read my subject...

I tried to achieve that with my computer, which has Windows 7 Ultimate.

I opened one Remote Desktop Client, logged successfully with User1.
I opened another RDC, but before login, Windows tells me that another user is currently logged on and must be disconnected before.

Is Dell representatives are lying to me? Which version of Windows ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop Windows editions have never allowed this and Windows 7 is no different. The Dell techs are simply mis-informed. There are third-party hacks out there to enable this functionality but I cannot personally vouch for their viability. They also most certainly violate Microsoft's Terms of Service and any support contracts you might have.

Comment: Thats what I thought. It's for a company, so hacking is NOT an option. So I must look for Server edition? It's a very small business and need only 2-3 simultaneous remote desktop connections. Any suggestions?

Comment: Server editions only allow 2 remote connections in administrative mode.  Going beyond that requires Terminal Server licensing.  You'll probably find 3 inexpensive PCs to be cheaper.

Comment: You may find using one robust machine to host 3 virtual machines for perople to connect to and use to be even cheaper. This is what I would do, either with ESXi or some sort of VirtualBox implementation. Though ESXi is also free if used on a single server with a single processor.

Comment: Basic VMware Server is also free and would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The PC being accessed (not the PC doing the accessing) must support multiple RDP sessions.

If you are trying to RDP to a remote machine and that REMOTE machine does not support multiple RDP sessions, it will inform you that you need to boot someone off.

Comment: The PC being accessed is a Windows 7 Ultimate. The Dell representatives told me that this version allowed this. They seam mis-informed, as Garrett said.